# Generate data for range of dates including those that are not present in data

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, date-range

Here is my table structure and data:

```
CREATE TABLE event (
    EventID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    EventDate DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    Description VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (EventID)
);

INSERT INTO event (EventID, EventDate, Description) VALUES
    (1, '2011-01-01 00:00:00', 'Event 1'),
    (2, '2011-03-01 00:00:00', 'Event 2'),
    (3, '2011-06-01 00:00:00', 'Event 3'),
    (4, '2011-09-01 00:00:00', 'Event 4');
```

And this query and output:

```
SELECT *
FROM EVENT
WHERE EventDate BETWEEN '2011-02-01' AND '2011-03-31'
```

```
+---------+---------------------+-------------+
| EventID | EventDate           | Description |
+---------+---------------------+-------------+
|       2 | 2011-03-01 00:00:00 | Event 2     |
+---------+---------------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want inject empty dates in the result like so:

```
+---------+---------------------+-------------+
| EventID | EventDate           | Description |
+---------+---------------------+-------------+
| NULL    | 2011-02-01 00:00:00 |  NULL       |
| NULL    | 2011-02-02 00:00:00 |  NULL       |
| NULL    | 2011-02-03 00:00:00 |  NULL       |
∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨
∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧
| NULL    | 2011-02-28 00:00:00 |  NULL       |
|       2 | 2011-03-01 00:00:00 |  Event 2    |
| NULL    | 2011-03-02 00:00:00 |  NULL       |
∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨∨
∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧∧
| NULL    | 2011-03-31 00:00:00 |  NULL       |
+---------+---------------------+-------------+
```

The output should contain 59 rows: 28 for February and 31 for March.

I'll want to avoid any hard coding; instead, I need a very flexible solution that adapts itself to the specified dates.

Comment: You may want to avoid 'hard coding', but efficiently creating a list of dates, comparing, inserting (and maybe even then deleting the list) will be much faster than attempting to calculate the individual dates.

Comment: @Dems: you're probably right, I didn't think of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An auxiliary calendar table will work well. The simplest possible calendar table is a single column of dates.

```
create table calendar (
    cal_date date primary key
);
```

You can use a spreadsheet or SQL to populate it. An outer join on it will bring in the dates that don't exist in your data. Limit permissions with GRANT and REVOKE, and use whatever means necessary to make sure that the dates you expect to be in there are actually in there. I run a daily report on my server that makes sure there are 'n' rows, and verifies the earliest and latest dates.

On some platforms, you can generate a series of dates on the fly, and either use it directly or in a CTE. PostgreSQL has functions for that; I don't know whether MySQL does. They're not hard to write, though, if you want to roll your own.

Comment: +1 : Comparing against a pre-created table is going to be sooooo much faster than writing code to calculate the individual missing dates.

Comment: @Dems: It's also inflexible. It realy depends on the variance of the date range.

Comment: @pablochan : I wouldn't say that it's inflexible.  The space taken by a calendar of 100 years is around 16KB; the time to create it on the fly if necessary is trivial; it can be customised to have fields such as DayOfWeek, BankHoliday, Opening Hours, etc; it can be a calendar of days, hours, weeks, months, etc; you can do almost anythign you like with it.  And it is a Massive performance boost in nearly every case.  Whatever it's costs, flexibility is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need an pivot table, Take a look at that

pivot table schema

name: pivot
columns: {i : datatype int}

Populate

create foo table

schema foo

name: foo
column: value datatype varchar

```
insert into foo
values('0'),
values('1'),
values('2'),
values('3'),
values('4'),
values('5'),
values('6'),
values('7'),
values('8'),
values('9');

- insert 100 values
insert into pivot
select concat(a.value, a.value)
from foo a, foo b

- insert 1000 values
insert into pivot
select concat(a.value, b.value, c.value)
from foo a, foo b, foo c
```

your query

```
SELECT 
 Event.EventId,
 case when EventDate is null then DATE_ADD(periods.periodstart, INTERVAL auxtable.i DAY)
 else EventDate  end,
 Description

FROM
(
  select id, min(EventDate ) periodstart, max(EventDate) periodend,

  DATEDIFF(max(EventDate),min(EventDate )) as days
  FROM EVEN
  WHERE EventDate BETWEEN '2011-02-01' AND '2011-03-31'
) periods

inner join     

(
  select *
  from pivot
  where i >= 0 and i < 31 //max one month change with your needs
)auxtable
on auxtable.i < periods.days

left join Event
on Event.EventDate = DATE_ADD(periods.periodstart, INTERVAL auxtable.i DAY)
```

Comment: It sort of worked but overly complicated. Plus it requires me to populate table of sequential numbers.

Comment: well, that is an mystic technique from more pure sql. That was adopted by sql server with the instruction "pivot" never i needed read about that but not doubt that be more simple but i prefer portable sql though then I'll keep an eye

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure this is impossible in pure SQL, so your choices are:

- use a stored procedure/function
- do this in the app code, which seems pretty straight forward