# MySQL count and display all dates in a range

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, between, date-range

I have Problems with a MySQL query. I have the following table:

```
[id]
[from] DATE (Y-m-d)
[days] INT
[...]
```

and i have the two PHP variables `$start` and `$end`. I want to have this result for example:

```
$start = 2012-19-03
$end = 2012-24-03
$result = array(
[0] => COUNT of rows WHERE '2012-19-03' BETWEEN from AND from + INTERVAL days DAY
[1] => COUNT of rows WHERE '2012-20-03' BETWEEN from AND from + INTERVAL days DAY
[2] => COUNT of rows WHERE '2012-21-03' BETWEEN from AND from + INTERVAL days DAY 
[4] => COUNT of rows WHERE '2012-22-03' BETWEEN from AND from + INTERVAL days DAY
[5] => COUNT of rows WHERE '2012-23-03' BETWEEN from AND from + INTERVAL days DAY 
[6] => COUNT of rows WHERE '2012-24-03' BETWEEN from AND from + INTERVAL days DAY 
}
```

Till now I was doing this in a while loop with a query for each day but there should be a better way. My Problem is the `GROUP BY`, where the days that not exist in the data.

More detailed example:

Sample data:

```
id, from,       days
1,  2012-15-03, 2
2,  2012-15-03, 5
3,  2012-13-03, 20
4,  2012-16-03, 1
```

Desired result:

```
$start = 2012-11-03
$end = 2012-19-03
$result = array(
[0] => 0 (ROWS IN DB WHERE '2012-11-03' BETWEEN from AND from+days -- no match in data),
[1] => 0 (ROWS IN DB WHERE '2012-12-03' BETWEEN from AND from+days -- no match in data),
[2] => 1 (ROWS IN DB WHERE '2012-13-03' BETWEEN from AND from+days -- id #3 matches),
[3] => 1 (and so on),
[4] => 3,
[5] => 4,
[6] => 3,
[7] => 2
)
```

like this..

hing hours without finding a way I hope you can help me,
Greetings

Comment: so where is the problem if you know the between keyword

Comment: to get this sort of array ordered and grouped by days between the PHP variables $start and $end

Comment: can you post the array you are getting from the db also the select sql query

Comment: i have no query, i ask for one

Comment: @Feryaz: [Generate a range of dates when those dates are not present in the data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6830654/87015)?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT `from`, COUNT(*) TotalRows
FROM tableName
WHERE `from` <= date('$start') AND `from` >= date('$end')
GROUP BY `from`
ORDER BY `from`
```

Comment: I dont want them ordered by from, they should be ordered by the days from the PHP variabls.

Comment: ok, so what do you mean by `days from the PHP variable`? can you elaborate further? thanks..

Comment: if $start is '2012-19-03' and $end is '2012-20-03'. the first element of array should have the value "COUNT of rows WHERE '2012-19-03' BETWEEN from AND from + INTERVAL days DAY" and the second "COUNT of rows WHERE '2012-20-03' BETWEEN from AND from + INTERVAL days DAY". That means its get ordered by the days between $start and $end.

Comment: by removing `ORDER BY from`, does it satisfy your requirements?

Comment: Wrong. It does not take into account the `BETWEEN from AND from + INTERVAL days` part.

Comment: @johntotetwoo no. it gets still grouped by from and i need the index by days between $start and $end.

Comment: @SalmanA yes, but thats not where i having problems so we can skip it.

Comment: @Feryaz to make it more clear, can you provide a dummy records above? (eg. sample record from table and your desired output)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what exactly you asked

But Seems you can use sum with if /else  and group by to achive :

like below :

```
select sum(if( '2012-19-03' BETWEEN `from` AND date_Add(`from` , INTERVAL days DAY)),1,0)) as firstdaycount,
sum(if( '2012-20-03' BETWEEN `from` AND date_Add(`from` , INTERVAL days DAY)),1,0)) as secondaycount,
..
....
.....
......
.....
where [...]
Group By ...
```

Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: That would mean i need to build the querie in a loop, isnt there a more flexible one? the $start and $end variables are not always the same and havnt always the same amount of days between.

Comment: Tried @johntotetwoo solution . NOt exacly you want ?